# Disposable mail for anonymity

Tags: email, anonymity

Initially asked in [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32915), I wanted to know how is it supposed to be used for anonymity. I mean that I need to register wallets and buy bitcoins. For anonimity, guitedlines recommend to use disposable mail. How is that? Isn't disposable mail features public exposure of your communication and possible loss of information since I do not control the mail clean up? How can this enforce my anonymity and security? What is exact step-by-step procedure implied?

Answer (score 1):

Anonymity from whom? Governments, or the average person you are making bitcoin exchanges with. These two differ widly. In the first (govs), anonymity is a bit more difficult since most people don't focus much on operational security (OPSEC) so little is thought about weaving together an alter ego. This means, most people are under the impression that they could use a proxy here, proxy there, maybe log in from Starbucks or some other coffee shop, and they're anonymous. The reality is, it all depends on what one does with this "pseudo" anonymity.

For the latter (making exchanges), where you would want to stay "pseudo" anonymous, a throwaway e-mail is sufficient. The average person is not going to get logfiles from service providers telling them who signed into a particular e-mail account, from what IP address. Even if they did, they would need to go to the ISP to figure out who the IP was allocated to. This becomes complicated.

Free mail... You get what you pay for. While I believe most e-mail service providers perform their due diligence in protecting your privacy, you need to remember they are all bound by laws. So if you intend on breaking any laws via way of bitcoin, anonymity is close to non existent without operational security.

**TECHNICAL RESPONSES NOW** Because my answer seems more to the tune of something which should be on a shady forum, I will talk about the technical sides of finding individuals. Using an example forensics/incident response case...

Someone registered a site, then used one of those domain proxies to hide their identity. This particular site was hosting information stolen from machines. My goal was to determine WHO owned the site, so I proceeded to go backwards using [Archive.org](http://Archive.org). I viewed the site when it was created 5,6,7-10 years ago. In the 2nd year it was created, the website owner had one of those generic counters, tied to a username. From the username, I was able to piece together who owned the site. This is what I mean by operational security. Things have to be planned well thought, with an emphasis on keeping one's identity not only secret, but with attention deflected elsewhere for anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late answer but it could help. I guess the recommendation of using disposable e-mail accounts when using BitCoins in terms of anonymity comes because it's much more 'likely' it won't be tracked when using an anonymous website which will most likely destroy all data after a certain amount of time rather than using a well-known free e-mail provider service.

As far as I know, most of these disposable services promise to destroy any data after the account expires (evidently, you cannot know that). But what you know is that when using a worldwide known free e-mail service provider there will most likely be a few dozens of backups of any data that might have arrived to your mailbox, not to mention access IP logging, etc.

As far as disposable services fo, you will usually find two ways of working:

- **Mailboxes**, which would be the best choice in terms of anonymity for services like BitCoins, etc. An example website is [MailDrop](http://maildrop.cc).
- **Forwardings**, which wouldn't help you very much in this case because it's just an e-mail address that would act as a proxy between the origin and the end-point (your e-mail address), but helps fighting problems like spam and UCE. An example is [No-Spammers](https://www.no-spammers.com).